# Postgres SQL 15.4 update trigger

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create an after update trigger on the postgres DB (**version 15.4**).
The update of a boolean column should update the date column of the same row only.
I have tried the following code set

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trpopulate_tablecolumn
AFTER UPDATE OF columnname ON tablename
FOR EACH ROW    
WHEN OLD.ColumnName<>NEW.ColumnName
EXECUTE FUNCTION fnupdate_functionname();
```

This gives me an error -"Syntax error near OLD"
I have also tried the similar logic in the function - but all the rows in the table gets updated.
The following is the code for the trigger function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fnupdate_functionname() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $BODY$


BEGIN  
  IF (OLD.columnname IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.columnname) THEN
  UPDATE tablename SET columnname_utc=(select current_timestamp at time zone 'utc')  where NEW.columnname<>OLD.columnname;
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;


 END;   


$BODY$


LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Can any body help?
I want only the impacted row to the updated with the trigger.
Another question is about the Each Row option - my table will have lots of rows - will the trigger be attempted for each row? Not the only impacted row? I am afraid about the performance.

Comment: Your function definition just runs a bare `UPDATE` (no where clause) - of course it updates all the rows in the table. Either use a BEFORE trigger and just set `NEW.columnname_utc` or restrict the update based on primary-key.

Comment: @RichardHuxton - thanks for your response. There was mistake in copy and paste from my part I have updated it now. And there is a where clause.

Comment: That's a useless WHERE clause though, isn't it? It's always going to be `TRUE` because you've already checked OLD vs NEW in the IF. Just write the query you want to execute: `UPDATE ... SET ... WHERE id_column = NEW.id_column` or something.

Comment: @RichardHuxton - this is what I have also just figured out. Thanks for your inputs. It certainly helped. But I am somehow intrigued about the WHEN in the trigger it self - why do I get the syntax error there?

Comment: @RichardHuxton - I figured out the reason behind the syntax error. The brackets were missing there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there were two issues, one is the incorrect where clause in the update statement of the function. Thanks to @RichardHuxton for pointing out.
The second issue (syntax error) - was due to a missing brackets.
And to answer the third question - the "For each row" indeed process every row in the DB. But this must be limited with the WHEN (where clause).

Thanks for your support :).

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, the way you would normally do this is in a BEFORE trigger and just set NEW.columname_utc

Comment: @RichardHuxton - when I tried to use BEFORE trigger earlier, it the PGAdmin suggested me to use AFTER trigger. So I stuck to that in my solution.

Comment: An `after trigger` cannot alter column values. I do not understand how/why pgAdmin would/could make such a suggestion. It is just wrong.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).